# python - Data-driven (read from file) - Test cases not run

Tags: python, robotframework, data-driven

I have a python code with Robot FW code. My Suite is like:

**Settings**

- Library
- BuiltIn Library
- Collections Library
- String Library
- DataDriver  file=C:/input.xlsx

**Test Cases**

`pre run test`

**Keywords**

```
TPT_TEST
  [Arguments]     ${v}     ${json1}
   COMMO ${v} ${json1}

`C:/input.xlsx` contains:
```

**Test Cases**

```
${v}    ${json1} test1             ver_1    C:/j1.json test2               ver_2    C:/j1.json
```

I have another robot file with the keywords:

```
@keyword('COMMO ${v} ${json1}')
def run_json(self, ver, json1):
   print(ver)

@keyword('pre run test')
def pre_run(self):
   print("Pre run test")
```

The current results I get is "COMMO" runs twice - which is great (once for each TC: test1/2)

I want to run `pre run test`. I want it to run only once! It does not happen. How I do it? What is the problem that `pre run test` does not run?

Please please advice

Thanks all. Matan

Comment: please try to reformat your question. It is really hard to read.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess you want to run the keyword "pre run test" exactly once? 

If so, you you define ```Suite Teradown   pre run test```, to run it only once.